# How to properly add a "+1" to the php variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a little lost with one of my variables and need your help. I am trying to add the +1 to default to my phone number variable so I don't have to use it on front.

Current row:

```
$this->sendSMS($plainMessage, $users['mobile_number']);
```

What I tried is next:

```
$mobile_number = "+1" . $mobile_number
$this->sendSMS($plainMessage, $users['mobile_number']);
```

I am pretty sure it's wrong but my brain is stuck.

Comment: You're not passing `$mobile_number` as argument in next line.

Comment: I tried changing it from $users['mobile_number'] to $mobile_number but that didn't really help since it's not from a db.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Could you print the output of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, what's front, and how it's not from a db?

Comment: @wSkc I am trying to add the +1 to whatever the mobile_number is in our database.

Comment: Maybe that `"+1".$users['mobile_number']` ?

Comment: Or `$this->sendSMS($plainMessage, '+1' . $users['mobile_number']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
$mobile_number = "+1" . $users['mobile_number'];
$this->sendSMS($plainMessage, $mobile_number);
```

Option 2:

```
$this->sendSMS($plainMessage, "+1" . $users['mobile_number']);
```

Spaces before and after dot are not necessary.